# .NET httpclient not saving a pdf file consistently

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a httpclient to save a file from an URI. The pdf is not saving a pdf file consistently. I solved the problem but I wanted to see if anyone can explain why this happened in the first place. The original code was:

```
using (var pdfStream = File.Create(savePdf))
                       result.Content.CopyToAsync(pdfStream);
```

The code that worked was:

```
File.WriteAllText(savePdf, result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: `Text` in that call sounds dangerous. Text handling routines often do character set transformations, and that can break PDFs.

Comment: Are you referring to the first or the second. And if the second is there something you recommend?

Comment: *Are you referring to the first or the second.* - the second. Method names like `WriteAllText` and `ReadAsString` indicate that the data is handled like text which includes stuff like encoding according to some character set encoding while writing and decoding while reading. Such operations may be destructive for binary data, though, and pdf is a binary Format. I have no recommendation, though, but i don't have any idea what you mean by *not saving a pdf file consistently* to start with.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is navigate to a URI which is a PDF and save that PDF to file.

Comment: Darrel's answer shows the actual solution. I merely pointed out that trying to use *text processing* methods is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

CopyToAsync returns a Task before the task has completed.  Your Using block will exit and pdfStream will be disposed before the CopyToAsync method has completed.

Either add await or .Wait().